# How to keep your beer cold up to 12 hours?

Tags: hiking, camping, backpacking

How can i keep my beer cold up to 12 hours while hiking ??

Comment: Where are you hiking? If you are in the arctic I don't think this will be a problem. Also drinking ale, wine or spirits does (depending on temperature) reduce the need to keep stuff cold.

Comment: Can't you just do without your beer for 12 hours?

Comment: This question might be met with better reception if you declared "drink" instead of beer. Not everyone agrees with people carrying intoxicating drinks while they're out in the backcountry.

Comment: Put it a chilly bin full of ice.

Comment: @ShemSeger I carry a can or two when hiking with my family. I can easily carry a 6 pack with going with friends. A 6 pack with 2-3 friends is no more than 2 beers each. I see no problem having a beer after a long day walking. it's actually pretty good but if the friend up here is planning to carry a whole keg, that is another story.

Answer (score 10):

If you are in a place that has streams, placing the beer in the water every time you take a break will cool them.
Place in a cold/cool body of water about 30 minutes before drinking will also help. 
If you don't have a body of water, wrap the individual cans/bottles in a wet towel in the shade, preferable where it is windy. Evaporation will cool the beers.

Last option will be to use some form of insulating container, keeping it will shaded in the backpack and add cold water just before drinking.

If you are in the USA look into Pat's Backcountry beer mixtures, that way you just add cold water from a stream/spring to have a cold beer.

Comment: Pat's Backcountry beer - is that dehydrated beer?! I wasn't aware such a thing existed :)

Comment: Pat's is indeed dehydrated beer, or a similar idea: condensed alcoholic flavour is added into pre-carbonated refreshing stream water using their special mixing container that allows the carbonation powder make it all taste very, very nice.

Answer (score 2):

(Caveat:  I don't drink while hiking)

A group I hiked with once locally used a [cooler tube](https://www.rei.com/product/898745/mountainsmith-cooler-tube).  It appeared to keep everything chilled on a warm-ish day in the Southeastern U.S.  There are quite a view vendors of similar products and it appeared to work well with a hiking setup for carrying.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a day hike, not an extended backpacking trip?  Then use a good cooler with dry ice.

Elaboration: Dry ice is colder than water ice (-78°C vs 0°C), and thus in a well-insulated cooler should keep anything cold longer.  It also has the advantage of sublimating instead of melting, so your load would become progressively lighter.  Of course you would probably need to practice a bit to figure out just how much dry ice to use so that you don't wind up with your beer still frozen solid at the end of the day.

OTOH, if it's a day hike, I would leave the drinks & food at the trailhead/camp site.  I've had no problem using regular ice for several days of cold food & drink when for instance camping with the horses.

Alternatively, you could get a solar electric cooler for use at the trailhead/camp site.

Comment: Can you elaborate somewhat more.

Answer (score -2):

Freeze a 24 oz can. It will bulge out.  Put it in a freezer bag.  Pack it in the middle of your sleeping bag.  Wrap your sleeping bag with your insulated pad.  Throw all of that in the freezer for 2-4 hours.

Comment: Hi Paparazzi! If I'm reading this right, it looks like you're suggesting putting the sleeping bag in the freezer. My sleeping bag would never fit in the freezer, especially with other things inside, so are you suggesting this for people with big freezers, or did you mean something else? It's probably my fault, but I'd appreciate clarification. Thanks!

Comment: @Sue You don't have to chill the bag.

Comment: @Sue The order is the order listed.  You don't have to chill the bag.

Comment: Okey doke. My mistake!